# bitwise operand in C simple issue

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a very simple and short question.

we have this code

```
void fun( unsigned value )
{ 
   unsigned c, displayMask = 1;  // 1 
   for ( c = 1; c <= 32; c++ ) 
   { 
      putchar( value & displayMask ? '1' : '0' );
      displayMask <<= 1; 
      if ( c % 8 == 0 ) 
         putchar( ' ' );
   } 
   putchar( '\n' ); 
}
```

This function prints the binary value of any unsigned number, but inverted. meaning if you insert `5` then it will print `101` followed by 29 zeros.

The question is, if we substitute `displayMask = 1` for `displayMask = 1 << 31 << 1` (where the `// 1` note is) what will be the output?

The correct answer is, that it will print 32 zeros no matter what value you inserted. But I don't understand why.

if we wrote `displayMask = 1 << 31 << 1` then at first it was `000...1`, then we rotated 31 times, so it is now `100...0` and then we rotated again so the 1 returns to the start and we again get `000...1`. What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: There are no rotations here

Comment: << is to rotate left no?

Comment: Nope. It is a shift operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` is not bit rotation but bit shift. Therefore `100...0 << 1` is 0, not 1.